# Compare two data sets by rank with Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have searched everywhere including this site and either I do not understand how to search for what I am looking for or it just isn't something folks are doing.

Basically, I have a data set from last week that shows names and ranks in their own columns. I now have a data set from this week with the same names but with different ranks. They are on the same sheet.

I simply want to compare and display the rank differences for every person. For example:

[Excel Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ia3Ev.jpg)

The red text is the result I am looking for... I obviously just hand jammed these in to the small sample.

Sorry about the formatting, not super savvy with this. Basically, if the above is my data set, I would want my third column to show the difference in rank between the weeks... so John Smith would be -1 and Tracie Mack would be 2.

Seems like there has to be a simple way of accomplishing this.

Thanks for any help guys,
jt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I begin, I want to say that almost always in cases like this, the best solution is to clean your data before trying to do any sort of analysis, even if the analysis is simple. If the ranks were in separate columns, this would be a simple exercise.

That said, you can do the analysis with the data as is. However, it's not a pretty formula and requires array entry.

Where your sample data is in A1:B6, select C1 and paste the following in the formula bar:

```
=VALUE(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1))-VALUE(INDEX(LEFT($B$1:$B$6,FIND(" ",$B$1:$B$6)-1),MATCH("*"&RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1)),$B$1:$B$6,0)))
```

After pasting, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will enter the formula as an array formula.

After entering the formula, fill it down the column.

[image]

Comment: Wow, that is an awesome answer but it looks like I messed up when trying to present the issue clearly and thoroughly... they are in separate columns. I should have used the | delimiter between the ranks and names.

Comment: So I did mention in the text that they were in their own columns but then I muddled it by using the | between some columns and not all in the example data. I have edited that to avoid further confusion. My bad.

Comment: I should have asked. When you said you wanted your third column to show the result, I took that as evidence that you really had the rank and name in the same cell.

Comment: Yea my bad on that too. I guess I was referring to the 3rd column, I meant the 3rd column of the second data set. I should have simply taken a snapshot like you did and attached it.

Comment: I updated my question again using the image upload tool built in to the forum. Thanks for all of your help thus far.

Comment: Ok, well looking at your solution that was more difficult because I wasn't clear enough, I was able to figure out the INDEX and MATCH formula well enough to suit my purposes. My end result was =VALUE(INDEX($D$3:$D$8,MATCH(F3,$C$3:$C$8,0))-G3)

Comment: Sorry to leave you hanging. I was planning on coming back to this to update it when I got a chance. I'm glad you found a solution.